# My ongoing issue with 2.79b and makehuman,The MHX2 format (MakeHuman eXchange 2)

Tags: file-format, makehuman

The MHX2 format (MakeHuman eXchange 2) My issue is the double instance
error in my copy of Blender(even though I have removed and reloaded numerous
times) I cant install the MHX2 plugin, not sure if it is a Win 10 problem
or Blender but have pretty much given up on using makehuman as I am unable
to use my fbx imports from makehuman as they will not bind to the rig and I am assuming it has to do with the way I am importing the makehuman models  to Blender.I have the makehuman tab in my tool tabs just not the plugins that make it work properly.anyone know how to fix this? I need to remove the double instance error but have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Try the zipped version of Blender instead of the installer. If it works there it's most likely a problem with Windows 10 rights management service.

Comment: thankyou will give it a try.